# How do I use "Transmit FTP in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm having trouble using the plugin "Transmit FTP" I do not know how to create a project and put data to synchronize local and remote.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to work with Transmit FTP?

Comment: Yeah I know. But how do I relate the FTP account in a project folder?

Answer (score 0):

To create/add a project, use the Proj script command: `:ProjAdd`. After that, when you want to upload (syncronize) the file you are working on (related to the project), just hit the `CTRL+U` keys.

Or manually add a folder to the proj file:

```
   [project] 
path = /path/to/project 
vim = /path/to/settings_file.vim 
docksend ; boolean option 

[path-with-spaces] 
path = /path/to/my\ project ; Escape spaces with \
```

See the help of the proj script for more details.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would like to download the entire project for my computer and work on it and just do CTRL + `U` to synchronize the files, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I like to do `vim scp://user@server/path/file`

Answer (score 0):

Transmit has a feature called "Disk" that mounts your server on your desktop allowing you to work more or less like if your files were local. The performance is not very good but you can manage your files and buffers how you want.

But I don't think that kind of workflow is really optimal for large projects. You should consider using a VCS and a local server instead.